# I'm not able to make call to external javascript in kendo ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI in that i'm not able to make call to the external scripts its throwing error "**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** "

Comment: please share some relevant code that you have tried and show us how you are using jquery library and other plugins

Comment: i have share the relvant code

Comment: @JKumar I don't see any code, I see an error message

Answer (score 0):

Look if you're referencing .js files multiple times, or in an incorrect order.

It'd be helpful if you shared some relevant code.